# SSL still displaying as unsecure

Tags: apache, ssl

I'm trying to set up my SSL certificate but the site still says that https is unsecure.

I've edited the 000-default.conf as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName millingtonmayers.co.uk
    Redirect permanent / https://millingtonmayers.co.uk/
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName millingtonmayers.co.uk
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/bensleym/millingtonmayers.co.uk.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/bensleym/millingtonmayers.co.uk.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/bensleym/intermediate.crt
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless

    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
 </VirtualHost>
```

The redirect doesn't seem to be working either any ideas?

Comment: Assuming ServerName the actual domain name the certificate its serving looks like you generated it yourself (self-signed) is that the case?

Comment: Yes I must of but don't know how how should I have set it up?

Comment: For public websites you cannot use a certificate you have generated yourself, that's only useful on your own machine or a network you control like an intranet.  A certificate must be from a trusted authority to work for anyone which means you need to spend a few dollars & buy one https://www.sslshopper.com/cheapest-ssl-certificates.html

Comment: I brought the SSL certificate from godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Have signed the certificate(millingtonmayers.co.uk.crt) from CA? when i inspect it says :

```
Start Time: 1499176042
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

if it is self-singed it is untrusted.
you can check this using "openssl s_client -connect millingtonmayers.co.uk:443" on a console

Comment: How do I sign it in that case?

Comment: 1. Genarate key and the csr  "openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout millingtonmayers.co.uk..key -out millingtonmayers.co.uk..csr"

Comment: I used this to generate the key openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout millingtonmayers.co.uk.key -out millingtonmayers.co.uk.csr

Comment: For a *public* website this is simply not going to work for your users.

Answer (score 0):

certificate signing process as follows:

1. Genarate key and the csr
   "openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout millingtonmayers.co.uk.key -out millingtonmayers.co.uk..csr"

2.Send the CSR for CA agent like comodo (https://www.instantssl.com/free-ssl-certificate.html).you will get the following certificates from the CA.
 CA agent will provide 3 certs

2.1.The Root Certificate

2.2.Intermediate certificates

2.3. millingtonmayers.co.uk.crt

You can get 90 days free cert from above

3.concatanate the above 3 certificate to one.

`cat  millingtonmayers.co.uk.crt DigiCertCA.crt TrustedRoot.crt   >millingtonmayers.co.uk.concatanated.crt`

4.configure the millingtonmayers.co.uk.concatanated.crt and millingtonmayers.co.uk.key to lb

Comment: Thank you for your time I used godday and then send me 2 files once valid. On point 4 what do you mean by "to lb"?

Comment: LB -Load balancer but if you don't have one just ignore.

Comment: for inspecting the crt you can use KeyStore Explorer(http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) nice tool.

Comment: Thanks tried redoing the key with go daddy but again it comes up self signed. What would my config look like if I did step 3?

Comment: SSLCertificateFile /home/bensleym/millingtonmayers.co.uk.concatanated.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/bensleym/millingtonmayers.co.uk.key
    # SSLCertificateChainFile /home/bensleym/intermediate.crt

Comment: seems your configurations point to self-signed one.insted of CA singed.are you sure that the file location is  /home/bensleym/

Comment: Thanks I'll give the free one a try and see if any different

Comment: it is not with the cert but configuration, whats the server you are going to configure?

Comment: Sorry yes I'm sure its correct thats where the key and csr are

Comment: Its an apache server

Comment: I run the code bellow to get the key then go to godady and submit the key. They verify it and then provide me with a link to download the files. I then drop the files in to home/bensleym via file zilla ftp

Comment: how would i do this?

Comment: So I have established that its not reading the new cert and is looking at a old one.

Comment: chmod 400 millingtonmayers.co.uk.crt

Comment: what does the CA name provide during CSR generation process?